# Why is this citation not showing the journal name?

Tags: biblatex

I am using `Biber` with the option `\usepackage[backend=biber,style=numeric,sorting=none]{biblatex}`

There is a citation in my bib file as follows:

```
@misc{steinhubl2018digital,
 title={Digital medicine, on its way to being just plain medicine},
 author={Steinhubl, Steven R and Topol, Eric J},
 year={2018},
 publisher={Nature Publishing Group},
 }
```

Which is printing in the bibliography as

```
[1] Steven R Steinhubl and Eric J. Topol. Digital
medicine, on its way to being just plain medicine.
2018.
```

There is no quote across the title, nor does it print the publisher's name. This is happening only for this entry, other entries are coming fine.

Comment: Your bib file entry seems to correspond to the following journal article: https://www.nature.com/articles/s41746-017-0005-1 If that's correct, `misc` is not the correct category. Use `article` instead and add the missing `journal` field.

Comment: Thank you @leandriis, it solved the problem. But other entries did not have any journal field, and still working (with only publisher=). The citation was taken from google scholar, they specified it as misc  :( .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@misc` is sort of the 'fallback' entry type in case the entry you want to cite does not fit into one of the usual entry types (`@article`, `@book`, `@incollection`, `@online`, ...). Often it is best to try and use a more specific and appropriate entry type before falling back to `@misc`.

The paper you want to cite (https://doi.org/10.1038/s41746-017-0005-1) appears to be a normal journal article (albeit in a digital journal), so the following entry appears to be more appropriate

```
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber,style=numeric,sorting=none]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{steinhubl2018digital,
  title   = {Digital medicine, on its way to being just plain medicine},
  author  = {Steinhubl, Steven R. and Topol, Eric J.},
  year    = {2018},
  journal = {npj Digital Med},
  volume  = {1},
  eid     = {20175},
  doi     = {10.1038/s41746-017-0005-1},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite{sigfridsson,steinhubl2018digital}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Steven R. Steinhubl and Eric J. Topol. “Digital medicine, on its way to being just plain medicine”. In: npj Digital Med 1, 20175 (2018). doi: 10.1038/s41746-017-0005-1.]

Specifically, the problem with the original entry was that `@misc` does not have a `journal` or `journaltitle` field and that the role of `publisher` is played by `organization`. You can look up the valid entry fields for each entry type in the standard `biblatex` data model in [the `biblatex` documentation, §2.1.1 *Entry Types* > *Regular Types*](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf).

[image: @misc A fallback type for entries which do not fit into any other category. Required fields: author/editor, title, year/date. Optional fields: subtitle, titleaddon, language, howpublished, type, version, note, organization, location, month, addendum, pubstate, doi, eprint, eprintclass, eprinttype, url, urldate]

Comment: Thank you for detailed explanations and additional data for my citation.